# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

By calculation, I guess this limit is 0, but I don't know how to prove it. Please give me some hints, thank you.

(Uniform convergence is useless here since the integrand is not uniform convergent on $[0,\pi]$, is it?)

Comment: You mean the limit as $n\to\infty$? Yes that is 0.

Comment: yes, could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Can you show that $$I =\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}x dx < \infty~?     ~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
There are several methods to show that. One of them is to divide $I$ into $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}x dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}x dx,$$
and show that the second integral is finite (by integration by parts for example) (the first one is obviously finite).

Then, with integration by substitution, you can use (1) to show that your limit is indeed 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the integral at for example $1/n$, and use the triangle inequality.

In the interval $[0,1/n]$ you estimate $|(\sin y)/y|\leq 1$, and so
$$
\Bigl|\int_0^{1/n}\frac{\sin nx}{nx}\,dx\Bigr|\leq \int_0^{1/n}1\,dx=1/n.
$$
In the interval $[1/n,\pi]$ you estimate $|\sin y|\leq 1$, and so
$$
\Bigl|\int_{1/n}^{\pi}\frac{\sin nx}{nx}\,dx\Bigr|\leq \int_{1/n}^{\pi}\frac{1}{nx}\,dx=\frac{\ln(\pi n)}{n}.
$$
Since both $\int_0^{1/n}$ and $\int_{1/n}^\pi$ tends to zero, the sum also tends to zero.

Answer (score 0):

First thank you for your answers, I found a method which can make use of uniform convergence a moment ago:

Note that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{b}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx=0$ since  $\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}$ is uniformly convergent to $0$, $\forall b\gt 0$. Then we can express $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx$ by $$\left\lvert\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx-\int_{b}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx\right\rvert + \left\lvert \int_{b}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}dx-0 \right\rvert $$

The former can be control to as small as enough by the definition of improper integral, the latter because of the fact noted above. The rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ argument is just the translation of the argument above.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{nx} \over nx}\,\dd x}}  =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n}\int_{0}^{n\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi + \pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\qquad\pars{~Stolz\mbox{-}Ces\grave{a}ro\ Theorem~}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over x + n\pi}
\,\dd x}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Moreover,
>   $\ds{0 < \verts{\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over x + n\pi}
> \,\dd x} < \int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over n\pi}\,\dd x = {1 \over n}}$.

$$
\mbox{So, with the 'Squeezing Theorem':}\quad
\bbx{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin\pars{nx} \over nx}\,\dd x = 0}}
$$